# Returning the size of an array in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am puzzled how Matlab returns the size of an array. Look at this:

```
a = zeros(2,100,10);
b = a(1,:,:);
size(b)

ans =
    1   100    10
```

I believe the answer should be

```
        100    10
```

Is there a simple way to get around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matlab removes only tailing singleton dimensions, otherwise a(1,:,:) would be 2D and a(1:2,:,:) 3D, which could be very confusing.

Try [squeeze](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html), it removes all singleton dimensions.

```
a = zeros(2,100,10);
b = squeeze(a(1,:,:));
size(b)

ans =

   100    10
```

Comment: Actually, it does remove _trailing_ singleton dimensions: `size(a(:,:,1))` is `2  100` (not `2  100  1`)

Comment: @LuisMendo: You are right, never noticed this because the resulting 2d-matrix could be indexed using `a(3,4,1)` as well.